# What is the best practice to modify an external image file of MediaStore in place?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

I am writing an android app in Android Q. I tried to modify an external image file acquired from the MediaStore in place.

The simplified logic is:

```kotlin
contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use {
  buffer = it.readBytes()
}

edit(buffer)

contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "wt").use {
  it?.write(buffer)
}
```

Also, `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">` is set. The image can be modified in place successfully, but I realize there is also some problem:

1. MediaStore is not updated immediately after the file is updated. e.g. the size of the file is still the old size.
2. Sometime calling `contentResolver.loadThumbnail` right after modifying the file will result in

```
W/MediaStore: Failed to obtain thumbnail for content://media/external/images/media/31
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

These problems lead me to think whether modifying the MediaStore file in place is an allowed action? If yes, what is the best practice to do this?

Comment: You can .update() the file size.

Comment: Yeah, it will help on a specific case, but I am wondering if there is some general update/notify function? 

Like once the file is changed, contentResolver or MediaStore can be requested to read the specific file and get its latest information.

Comment: No. You do that yourself with calling .update().

Comment: hmm the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#SIZE) says the size file is read-only, so I need another way to update it